# Is there a way to fix wrong tags restored in variable. php/laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to fix wrong tags automatically? I am using laravel PHP.

The data's already exist and i migrated it into to laravel so im having problems now.

Table 'destinations'

| id | value_name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | `<br>Australia</b>` |
| 1 | `<b>USA<b>` |
| 2 | `<i>UK<i>` |

My data has a tendency to have a wrong closing and opening tags in it.

My problem is I am trying to map it into pdf (tcpdf).
but it returns error because of the wrong closing and opening tags on the values.

Is There anyway to manipulate the data's?

Like:

"< br >Foo< /b >" to "< b >Foo< /b >"

"< b >Foo< b >" to "< b >Foo< /b >"

My Code is something like:

```
function ImportAsPdf(){
   $datas = DB::table('destinations')->get();

   $html = '<table>';
   foreach($datas as $data){
      $html .= "<tr><td>$data->value_name</td></tr>";
   }
   $html .= '</table>';

$pdf->printHTMLTable();
}
```

Comment: you can extract the first tag, put a slash after the first character, extract and replace it with a slashed tag. Regex can help you)

Comment: How are you saving the data? Where are you getting it from? Perhaps you should try to fix that part instead.

Comment: the data's already exist i just migrated it to laravel so im having a problems now

Comment: Is it a lot of data? How viable is it to fix it manually in the database?

Comment: Otherwise, preg_replace is probably your best bet.

Comment: It's more like a thousand rows. the data that i just put here is just my sample that cause the error

Comment: You can create jobs and divide data into chunks and then update the records @Azuren